# String.prototype.tokenize = tokenize;

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do lexical analysis for the xpl langauge with java and found

```
String.prototype.tokenize = tokenize;
```

but can't figure out what this line of code do !

Answer (score 2):

Its overrige/create `tokenize` method in `String` object.

For example now strings will have method `tokenize`:

```
alert('hello world'.tokenize());
```

Read more about prototype at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: The name OP used is `tokenize`, not `tokensize`. That is probably a function, so you might want to *call* it in the alert :)

Answer (score 0):

`String.prototype.tokenize = tokenize` means: add the method `tokenize` to the `prototype` of the `String` object. It's called [augmentation](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/javascript-the-good-parts-built-in-object-augmentation-and-namespacing) or [extending](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html) the prototype.

Let's say `tokenize` looks like this:

```
function tokenize(someToken){
  return this.replace(RegExp('%0','g'),someToken || '');
}
```

now `String.prototype.tokenize = tokenize` can be used like this:

```
var str = 'hello %0'.tokenize('world'); //=> 'hello world'
//or
var str = String.protoptype.tokenize.call('hello %0','world'); //=> 'hello world'
```